# MariaDB dependent subquery in the not in subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query that retrieves all rows (x:text,y:text) from table1 where text in column x is not yet in table2.x

Given:

- We are using MariaDB;
- the column x is defined as not nullable text in both tables;
- No indices are there (the application is very dynamic that we do not want to use indices);
- we need the column y to be retrieved as well (EXCEPT won't work).

The execution plan always shows the inner query as a Dependent Subquery and the performance is super bad.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(table1.x), table1.y
FROM table1
WHERE table1.x IS NOT NULL 
AND table1.x  NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT table2.x from table2
    WHERE table2.x IS NOT NULL
)
```

Could you please suggest some better solution to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of `NOT IN`. PS. `DISTINCT` is **not** a function.

Comment: *the column x is defined as not nullable* If so then what's the reason for to check that the value is not NULL? You do not trust the server? *No indices are there* - If so then fullscan is performed, hence the improvement is too doubtful..

Comment: Use *not exists*; Remove the `distinct`; remove the `where not null`.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following is any better for you:

```
select table1.x, table1.y -- use Distinct only if x & y have duplicates
from table1 t1
where not exists (select * from table2 t2 where t2.x = t1.x);
```

You obviously don't need to check for NULL is columns do not allow NULL. Probably the optimizer would ignore this anyway.

Comment: I think that this will be even slower.